# The `testDeviceID` prop of AdMobBanner is deprecated. Test device IDs are now set globally. Use AdMob.setTestDeviceIDAsync instead

Tags: react-native, admob, expo

I've recently been producing an app on a real-native basis. I also put in an ad banner using Google's admob There is no advertisement that used to appear until a few days ago.
Setting the admob props below will result in an error.

```
<AdMobBanner
    bannerSize="banner"
    adUnitID="ca-app-pub-@@@@@@@" 
    testDeviceID="EMULATOR"
    servePersonalizedAds = {true}
    onDidFailToReceiveAdWithError={this.bannerError} 
/>
```

The errors are as follows.

```
The `testDeviceID` prop of AdMobBanner is deprecated. Test device IDs are now set globally. Use AdMob.setTestDeviceIDAsync instead.
```

I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, They should update the information on the Expo site. I believe this should work for the banner as well.

Import:

```
import {
  setTestDeviceIDAsync, //<--- I forgot this first time
  AdMobInterstitial
}from 'expo-ads-admob';
```

init after mount:

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.initAds().catch((error) => console.log(error));
}

initAds = async () => {
 AdMobInterstitial.setAdUnitID('ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712') //test id
 await setTestDeviceIDAsync('EMULATOR');
}
```

Trigger this function from a button or what ever you like:

```
_openInterstitial = async () => {
  try {
    this.setState({ disableInterstitialBtn: true })
    await AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync()
    await AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync()
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  } finally {
    this.setState({ disableInterstitialBtn: false })
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I just want to clarify since I cannot see it on the documentation. Do I need to remove/replace `setTestDeviceIDAsync` once I will build my app for production/play store? If so, do what will be the replacement?